# Android: Intent's extra is missing (working with widget)

Tags: android, android-intent, widget, android-pendingintent

I want to make a widget with 2 Buttons(one is a Textview with a number). One button should increment the number and the other decrement it.

Here are my variables(2x action-names and an int for the number)

```
    private static final String PLUS_ONE = "Plus1";
    private static final String MINUS_ONE = "minus1";
    static int counter = 0;
```

The onUpdate():

```
 @Override
 public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
 final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
 for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
     int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
     RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.plus1counter_widget);
     remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.counter_widget, getPendingSelfIntent(context, PLUS_ONE, counter));
     remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.img_downWid, getPendingSelfIntent(context, MINUS_ONE, counter));

     appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
 }}
```

getPendingSelfIntent is my method to create an intent, putting an int value in it and returning an PendingIntent
Here in detail:

```
    protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action, int i) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Plus1CounterAppWidgetProvider.class);
    intent.setAction(action);
    intent.putExtra("safeInt", i);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);}
```

and eventually my onReturn() in which I want to set the counter to the value I gave to the Intent and perform the action:

```
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 super.onReceive(context, intent);
 counter = intent.getIntExtra("safeInt", 0); 

 if (PLUS_ONE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
     counter++;
     RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.plus1counter_widget);
     remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.counter_widget, Integer.toString(counter));
     AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, Plus1CounterAppWidgetProvider.class), remoteViews);
 }

 if (MINUS_ONE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
     counter--;
     RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.plus1counter_widget);
     remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.counter_widget, Integer.toString(counter));
     AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, Plus1CounterAppWidgetProvider.class), remoteViews);
 }}
```

By calling

```
counter = intent.getIntExtra("safeInt", 0);
```

the counter is always set to 0, which means that there is no extra value.
I just do not get why! Any Solutions? :)

Answer (score 0):

I found an other solution.
I just used SharedPreferences instead of the Intent and it worked! :)
Here is the code:

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class Plus1CounterAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider{

private static final String PLUS_ONE = "Plus1";
private static final String MINUS_ONE = "Minus1";
private static final String REFRESH_COUNTER = "Refresh";
static int counter = 0;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[]  appWidgetIds) {
 final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
 for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
     int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
     RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),  R.layout.plus1counter_widget);
     remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.counter_widget, getPendingSelfIntent(context, PLUS_ONE));
     remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.img_downWid, getPendingSelfIntent(context, MINUS_ONE));
     remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.img_refreshWid, getPendingSelfIntent(context, REFRESH_COUNTER));
     appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 super.onReceive(context, intent);

 SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("com.plus1counter.safeFile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 counter = sharedPref.getInt("safeFile", 0);
 if(counter == 100){
     counter = 0;
 }

 if (PLUS_ONE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
     counter++;
     writeSharedPrefs(sharedPref);         
 }

 if (MINUS_ONE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
     counter--;
     writeSharedPrefs(sharedPref);
 }

 if(REFRESH_COUNTER.equals(intent.getAction())){
     counter = 0;
     writeSharedPrefs(sharedPref);
 }
 RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.plus1counter_widget);
 remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.counter_widget, Integer.toString(counter));
 AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, Plus1CounterAppWidgetProvider.class), remoteViews);
 }

 public void writeSharedPrefs(SharedPreferences sharedPref){
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
 editor.putInt("safeFile", counter);
 editor.commit();
 }

 protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, Plus1CounterAppWidgetProvider.class);
 intent.setAction(action);
 return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 }

 }
```

Comment: here is the final application [plus1counter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apperrant.plus1counter)